Angular material table with sticky header, problem when using overflow-x
I have the following table
<div class="table-container" #scrollable>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" cdkScrollable>
    <!-- Definir columnas -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[column] }}</td>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Filas de datos -->
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>


CSS
.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
}

.fixed-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white; 
  z-index: 1;
}


Notice how in .table-container css overflow is commented. So far with that sticky header on the table is going to work.
..unless you uncomment the 'overflow-x' fragment inside the table container.
.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}


I have a similar scenario and have to add horizontal scrolling inside the table container (only for smaller screens), but by doing that the sticky header of the table isn't staying sticky at the top of the table when doing vertical scroll. Is there any way to achieve this?
Please relate to this stackblitz to see the full example.
Already tried chatGPT to find a solution but that was confusing lol

.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

this should fix it. You just need to provide height for your container. This should also help you with smaller screen size since it will book on view size of device.


A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to
value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it
scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting
the opposite edge of its containing block.

According to the definition of a sticky element, a sticky element is initially positioned relative to its containing block. It will remain in this position until it reaches the specified offset (top:0px) and then it will behave like its position is fixed relative to the containing block. And it will stay fixed until you reach the end of the containing block.
The browser will calculate the position of the sticky element with respect to the height of the containing block. Thus, the containing block must have a defined height for the browser to determine the position of the sticky element accurately.
So, you must specify the height of the containing block (table-container) in your CSS and also, make sure that your containing block is horizontally scrollable by setting overflow-x to auto.
Modifying the styles of table-container class as shown below will work:
.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: unset;
  height: 500px; /* Can be any defined height */
}


When you have overflow property on the parent element of sticky element, the sticky functionality won't work, you need to add the overflow-x: auto to the body instead
body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}

CSS:
.table-container {
  display: unset;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white; /* Ajusta el color de fondo según tu diseño */
  z-index: 1;
}

Stackblitz Demo
